# C++ Template - A parameter in a returned type - unexpected token preceding ';'

Tags: c++, templates

I have a following code:

```
template<bool SSL>
class WebSockets {
private:
   uWS::TemplatedApp<SSL>::WebSocketBehavior configureServer(); // error
   // uWS::TemplatedApp<false>::WebSocketBehavior configureServer(); // works
   // uWS::TemplatedApp<true>::WebSocketBehavior configureServer(); // works
};
```

And during building a solution I'm getting

> Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'WebSocketBehavior'
>
> Error C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

If I define manually false/true instead of use SSL, then it works well but I'd like to use the template parameter 'SSL'. What am I doing wrong? I don't have a lot of experience with templates.

Struct WebSocketBehavior and TemplatedApp is defined [here](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/src/App.h)

Comment: Try `typename uWS::TemplatedApp<SSL>::WebSocketBehavior`. If it helps, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Yes, thanks it helped. In the end, I found out that it will be more convenient for me use decltype(auto). Thanks for the link, it was really helpful for me. :)